# Cordova Input type number maxlength not working in android?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, cordova

I want to show the android number pad and apply the maximum limit 2.
I have used the `<input type="number" min="0" max="99"/>`. This code only works on the browser and not on android devices.

Does anyone know a suitable solution for this type of situation?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="99"/>
```

would work perfectly for web browsers.

In angularjs

```
<input type="tel" ng-model="value"/>
```

has to be used, this gives a keyboard with Numbers and Symbols.

Leveraging the concept of **$watch** in **angularjs** both the maximum limit and input type as number can be achieved.

> If the new value length is more than 2 then value of text field is set
>   to old value

```
$scope.$watch('value', function(newVal, oldVal) {
   if(newVal.length > 2) {       
      $scope.value = oldVal;
   }
}
```

Following is the regular expression for integers

```
 var onlyNumbers = /^\d+$/;
```

> If the new Value matches the regular expression then it returns an
>   array or else null. If the return type is null then value of text
>   field is set to old value

```
  var r = newVal.match(onlyNumbers);
    if(r===null){
      $scope.value = oldVal;
    }
```

The full solution is contained in the plunker link below:

https://plnkr.co/edit/WrZ3xKs9EcXOvCemuIck?p=preview

Comment: The input type="tel" works with the max length. But We want the solution for the input type="number". And here the maxlength is not getting applied.